# How to fill in the rows of the hourly timestamp with the last known price until the price column change and likewise continue further

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

How to fill in the rate with the previously known price for each hour until the price changes likewise fill in the rate until it changes in future.

```
 Provided Raw Dataset
 Date                   product         price
 2019-01-02 02:00:00        XVZ             22.00
 2019-01-02 05:00:00        XVZ             24.00
 2019-01-02 10:00:00        XVZ             24.50
 2019-01-02 12:00:00        XVZ             23.00
 2019-01-02 15:00:00        XVZ             27.00
 2019-01-02 19:00:00        XVZ             21.00

 Expected Desired RESULT:
 Date                   product         price
 2019-01-02 02:00:00        XVZ             22.00
 2019-01-02 03:00:00        XVZ             22.00
 2019-01-02 04:00:00        XVZ             22.00
 2019-01-02 05:00:00        XVZ             24.00
 2019-01-02 06:00:00        XVZ             24.00
 2019-01-02 07:00:00        XVZ             24.00
 2019-01-02 08:00:00        XVZ             24.00
 2019-01-02 09:00:00        XVZ             24.00
 2019-01-02 10:00:00        XVZ             24.50
 2019-01-02 11:00:00        XVZ             24.50
 2019-01-02 12:00:00        XVZ             23.00
 2019-01-02 13:00:00        XVZ             23.00
 2019-01-02 14:00:00        XVZ             23.00
 2019-01-02 15:00:00        XVZ             27.00
 2019-01-02 16:00:00        XVZ             27.00
 .
 .
 2019-01-02 19:00:00        XVZ             21.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`resample`](https://www.google.com/search?q=df+resample&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=df+resample&aqs=chrome.0.35i39j0l5.2112j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
df.set_index('Date').resample('H').ffill().reset_index()
```

Or [`asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
df.set_index('Date').asfreq('H').ffill().reset_index()
#df.set_index('Date').asfreq('H',method='ffill').reset_index()
```

---

```
                  Date product  price
0  2019-01-02 02:00:00     XVZ   22.0
1  2019-01-02 03:00:00     XVZ   22.0
2  2019-01-02 04:00:00     XVZ   22.0
3  2019-01-02 05:00:00     XVZ   24.0
4  2019-01-02 06:00:00     XVZ   24.0
5  2019-01-02 07:00:00     XVZ   24.0
6  2019-01-02 08:00:00     XVZ   24.0
7  2019-01-02 09:00:00     XVZ   24.0
8  2019-01-02 10:00:00     XVZ   24.5
9  2019-01-02 11:00:00     XVZ   24.5
10 2019-01-02 12:00:00     XVZ   23.0
11 2019-01-02 13:00:00     XVZ   23.0
12 2019-01-02 14:00:00     XVZ   23.0
13 2019-01-02 15:00:00     XVZ   27.0
14 2019-01-02 16:00:00     XVZ   27.0
15 2019-01-02 17:00:00     XVZ   27.0
16 2019-01-02 18:00:00     XVZ   27.0
17 2019-01-02 19:00:00     XVZ   21.0
```